# Modifying a prop that's an object is not detected by the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing this object as a prop to a component called `LoungeItem`:

```
lounge = {guests: [], _id: "60ec3840306969479c25b822", name: "Lounge_name"}
```

like this:

```
<LoungeItem lounge={lounge} />
```

If I add a guest to `lounge.guests` so it becomes like this:

```
lounge = {guests: [
      {_id: "60e5892d1e8b3c2c24c5463c", name: "username", surname: "usersurname", profile: {…}}
    ], _id: "60ec3840306969479c25b822", name: "Lounge_name"}
```

This change doesn't get detected inside `LoungeItem` and `componentWillReceiveProps` doesn't get triggered:

This is the component:

```
class LoungeItem extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(
      " ~ file: LoungeItem.js ~ line 18 ~ LoungeItem ~ componentWillReceiveProps ~ nextProps",
      nextProps
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { lounge } = this.props;
    console.log("===================INSIDE LOUNGE ITEM =================");
    console.log(
      " ~ file: PublicLoungeList.js ~ line 7 ~ PublicLoungeList ~ render ~ lounge",
      lounge
    );
    console.log("===================INSIDE LOUNGE ITEM =================");
    const guests = lounge.guests;
    console.log(
      " ~ file: LoungeItem.js ~ line 33 ~ LoungeItem ~ render ~ guests",
      guests
    );

    return <div>Lounge</div>;
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT 1:** As requested here's how lounge gets modified in the reducer:

```
case JOIN_LOUNGE:
  const newLounges = state.lounges.map((lounge) => {
    if (lounge._id == action.payload.lounge_id) {
      lounge.guests.push({
        _id: action.payload._id,
        name: action.payload.name,
        surname: action.payload.surname,
        profile: {
          _id: action.payload.profile._id,
          handle: action.payload.profile.handle,
        },
      });
      return lounge;
    } else {
      return lounge;
    }
  });
```

And for more details it's handled like this by `LoungesList` component:

```
class LoungesList extends Component {
  render() {
    const { lounges } = this.props;
    console.log(
      "===================INSIDE PUBLIC LOUNGE LIST================="
    );
    console.log(
      " ~ file: PublicLoungeList.js ~ line 7 ~ PublicLoungeList ~ render ~ lounges",
      lounges
    );
    console.log(
      "===================INSIDE PUBLIC LOUNGE LIST================="
    );

    return lounges.map((lounge) => {
      console.log(
        " ~ file: PublicLoungeList.js ~ line 19 ~ PublicLoungeList ~ returnlounges.map ~ lounge",
        lounge
      );
      return <LoungeItem lounge={lounge} />;
    });
  }
}
```

And that one is called here:

```
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return <PublicLoungeList lounges={this.props.lounges}></PublicLoungeList>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  lounges: state.chats.lounges,
});
```

Comment: How is Redux involved here? I see nothing related.

Comment: The modification of guests is done through redux. But, I didn't add it here because it doesn't make a difference whether the change was done through redux or by the parent component itself.

Comment: It may depend on how you're modifying the property, e.g., if you're modifying the property "in place" `lounge` will be the same object, and may not trigger an update.

Comment: Agreed. You need to make sure you're replacing `lounge` with a new object (e.g. using `Object.assign`), not a modified version in the same place (e.g. via in-place assignment). If you'd like us to help, you should show us the code that updates `lounge`.

Comment: I am simply pushing a guest to lounge.guests. If this doesn't count as a "prop change", how should I update lounge in a way that would make the change get detected.

Comment: I just added the request redux code.

Comment: You're mutating `lounge.guests` which is a big no no in react

Comment: @Jamiec What do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mutate `lounge.guests`, instead use the spread operator to build a new lounge with an updated array

```
case JOIN_LOUNGE:
  const newLounges = state.lounges.map((lounge) => {
    if (lounge._id == action.payload.lounge_id) {
     return {
       ...lounge,
       guests: [...lounge.guests,{
        _id: action.payload._id,
        name: action.payload.name,
        surname: action.payload.surname,
        profile: {
          _id: action.payload.profile._id,
          handle: action.payload.profile.handle,
        },
      }]
     }
    } else {
      return lounge;
    }
  });
```